# Footings for loft

Tags: concrete

I put 2×2' pad with 5/8 rebar 16 oc both ways is that sufficient for 4×16 pearlam sitting on 6×6 posts every 8' with 2×10 joists 16 oc for a loft as an office in a Warehouse

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's going to be hard to help you without more info (e.g. a diagram); even then, you may need to talk to a structural engineer.

Comment: How far do the 2x10’s span?

Comment: Do the joists span from wall to beam, or do they continue past beam?

Answer (score 1):

If the 2x10’s spanned 12’, then 6’ of the load would transfer to the beam. Therefore, the load on the beam is:
40 psf live load + 15 psf dead load for a total load of 55 psf. If the joists span 12’ (6’ transfers to beam) then the load on the beam is: 55 psf x 6’ = 330 plf on beam

If the posts are 8’ o.c., then the load on each post is: 330 psf x 8’ = 2640 lbs plus column plus footing.

The footing and column weigh about 600 lbs.  So, the total load on the soil is: 2,640 lbs. + 600 = 3,240 lbs.  Therefore, the load on the soil is: 3,240 / 4 square feet of footing = 810 lbs. per square foot. This is very minor and unless you live where the ground is mush, the soil will support your load. (Code requires a souls analysis when you assume the bearing value is 1500 psf or more.)

The rebar should be find, as the footing is not in jeopardy of having the post puncture the footing nor make the footing bend so it will break.